# Create a 7z Archive for files created by date using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have directory where various daily files gets copied. I need to write a power shell script which will create `7z` archive based on groups of file create date.The name of the archive includes those group dates.

Example Below

```
FileA  06/23/11
FileB  06/23/11
FileC  06/24/11
```

Script should create 2 archives

```
062311.7z contains FileA, FileB
062411.7z contains FileC
```

Thanks in advance

--------- Now I have to develop a compression routine which can take care of daily/Weekly/ Monthly durations

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you need to do is group all the files via date using group-object:

```
$groups = dir | group-object -property {$_.LastWriteTime.Date}
```

then for each group, build a command string that does your zipping and execute it:

```
$groups | foreach{$cmd = "7z.exe a $((Get-Date $_.Name).ToString(`"MMddyy`")).7z $([string]::join(`" `", $_.Group))"; invoke-expression $cmd}
```

**Warning**, the above is not really tested (for ex. it won't work if you spaces in your filename). But hopefully, it will give you enough to proceed.

Comment: What kind of updates are you looking for?  Were there issues with running the code that zdan provided?